# C# Dispatcher and progressbar blocked

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, dispatcher

I'm new with C# and I want to show a loading window with an indeterminate progressbar during the execution of a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, I try something like this:

```
progressbarwin = new Windows1();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, (Action)delegate
     {
       //Do something
        progressbarwin.Close();
     });

progressbarwin.ShowDialog();
```

The window is showed (before the delegate) but the progressbar is blocked. What can I do?

@Sinatr
I tried to open the Windows from a new thread UI:

```
Thread loadT = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    Loading progressbarwin = new Loading();
    progressbarwin.ShowDialog();
}));
// Set the apartment state
loadT.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
// Make the thread a background thread
loadT.IsBackground = true;
// Start the thread
loadT.Start();
//Do something
loadT.Abort();
```

but it gives me a cross thread exception when i create the window (new Loading())

@Mitra M 
It's the same :(

Comment: This looks like what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036279/wpf-progress-bar-update-with-dispatcher

Comment: You are trying to report progress wrongly, the whole operation will run at once (thus blocking UI) in UI thread. Instead either run it in another thread dispatching only short calls to UI or split into steps, using e.g. `DispatcherTimer` (or timer can simply poll progress).

Comment: put `progressbarwin.Show();` before the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...` , instead of `progressbarwin.ShowDialog();`